# Initialization of mat within mat

Tags: mat

I'm using EM on an array and I wish to store the results of EM (means, sigma etc.) in an array. Therefore, I need a Mat of Mat object, since the means,sigma etc., are in Mat form. Can somebody tell me how to initialize such an array? The size of the Mat I need is approximately 200000*3. With each column storing the means, weights and sigma values of the mixtures.

Basically, I need a 200000*3 Mat in which every element is an N*1 Mat. Any help with this please?